# Depedendency Injection on base Controller / Service

Tags: symfony, service, controller, dependencies, code-injection

i'm very new in Symfony. I began my first project in symfony 2.3 LTS. At this time i have created many controllers in different bundles. My question relates to a correct procedure. I use in my controllers different services, like 'translator', 'form factory', 'session', 'router', 'entitymanager', 'templating'.

I create in my "service.yml" a base service

```
myapp.controller.base:
    class: "%myapp.controller.base.class%"
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", , "@templating", "@session", "@translator", "@router", "@form.factory"]
```

and inject the base service in my controller, which is also a service.

```
myapp.controller.locales:
    class: "%myapp.controller.locales.class%"
    arguments: ["@myapp.controller.base"]
```

My base service look like this.

```
namespace MyApp\<BundleName>\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class BaseController
{
protected $formErrorService;
protected $entityManager;
protected $templating;
protected $session;
protected $translator;
protected $router;
protected $formFactory;

public function __construct($entityManager, EngineInterface $templating, Session $session, $translator, $router, $formFactory)
{
    $this->setEntityManager($entityManager);
    $this->setTemplating($templating);
    $this->setSession($session);
    $this->setTranslator($translator);
    $this->setRouter($router);
    $this->setFormFactory($formFactory);
}

 public function setEntityManager($em)
{
    $this->entityManager = $em;
}

public function getEntityManager()
{
    return $this->entityManager;
}
```

public function setTemplating($templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

```
public function getTemplating()
{
    return $this->templating;
}

public function setSession($session)
{
    $this->session = $session;
}

public function getSession()
{
    return $this->session;
}

public function setTranslator($translator)
{
    $this->translator = $translator;
}

public function getTranslator()
{
    return $this->translator;
}

public function setRouter($router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function getRouter()
{
    return $this->router;
}

public function setFormFactory($formFactory)
{
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
}

public function getFormFactory()
{
    return $this->formFactory;
}
}
```

And i call in my locales controller look like this

```
namespace MyApp\<Bundlename>\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class LocalesController extends BaseController
{

protected $baseService;

public function __construct($baseService)
{
    $this->baseService = $baseService;
}

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

$locales=$this->baseService->getEntityManager()->getRepository('<reponame>')->findAll();
    return  $this->baseService->getTemplating()->renderResponse('<templatename>', array('locales' => $locales));
}
```

Is this a correct procedure? Should i use this procedure in ervery controller which i need this services?

I hope i get useful hints, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an incorrect way to inject one controller to another. You should use `parent` for your child controllers.

Example:

```
myapp.controller.base:
    class: "%myapp.controller.base.class%"
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", , "@templating", "@session", "@translator", "@router", "@form.factory"]

myapp.controller.locales:
    class: "%myapp.controller.locales.class%"
    parent: myapp.controller.base
```

More docs about parent services and overriding parent dependecies: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html